# how to parse a value to a 2Dtext in spark ar

Tags: instagram, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I have an X value representing how much I open my mouth in spark AR. How can I show that X value into a 2d text?

I expect the text to show the Number value while running the effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use this script:

```js
const Scene = require('Scene');

// Use export keyword to make a symbol available in scripting debug console
export const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');

// To use variables and functions across files, use export/import keyword
// export const animationDuration = 10;

// Use import keyword to import a symbol from another file
// import { animationDuration } from './script.js'

// To access scene objects
// const directionalLight = Scene.root.find('directionalLight0');

// To access class properties
// const directionalLightIntensity = directionalLight.intensity;

// To log messages to the console
Diagnostics.log('Console message logged from the script.');

const Patches = require('Patches');

const numberFormat = '{0}';
const number = Patches.getScalarValue('number');

Patches.setStringValue('value', number.format(numberFormat));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oboNx.png)